# Is there an easy way to stream my music

Tags: ruby, streaming, sinatra

Is there any easy way to build a Sinatra app, which can build out of multiple files one audio stream.

So my questions are:
Is there any gem for that?
How is this called what i wanna do?
Or is there an example for that out in the web?

Comment: Something like [ice cast](http://www.icecast.org/)?

Comment: ice cast looks not bad but I'm not sure if there is an easy way to add my files on the fly to ice cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with mpd & icecast if someone has the same problem.